# Maximum recursion depth

Tags: python

I keep getting the Maximum recursion depth and I don't know how to fix it. Could someone help me? Here is my code:

```
with open("input.txt") as file:

    def remove_string_recursive():

        with open("input.txt") as file:

            for line in file:

                string, letter = line.strip().split(",")
 
                if (len(string) == 0): 
                    return "" 

                if (string[0] == letter): 
 
                    return remove_string_recursive() 

                return string[0] + remove_string_recursive() 

string = remove_string_recursive() 
  
print(string + "," + letter)
```

If it helps, my code is meant to have the same input and output as the following but using a recursive format.

```
with open("input.txt") as file:

    def remove_from_string():

        with open("input.txt") as file:
    
            for line in file:

                string, letter = line.strip().split(",")
   
                res_str = string.replace(letter, '') 
   
                print (res_str + "," + letter)

remove_from_string()
```

Comment: The error is pretty easy to see: you are running the function recursively either way.

Comment: Your recursive calls are running on the same `line` over and over without termination. if `string[0] == letter` is true, you never reach the next `line`

Comment: It's not the source of the error, but do you realize for this code it's bad practice to have your function definition inside the with block?

Comment: A recursive function with no parameters is fundamentally nonsense.  For the recursion to ever finish, there has to be some state in which no recursive call is made, and each call has to move steadily towards such a state.  But with no parameters, you don't actually *have* any state, it will either never recurse, or recurse infinitely.

Comment: If you're looking for a fix to your code it would help if you describe what it actually supposed to do because we can't guess

Comment: This code is too broken to guess its purpose.  Can you provide a short description of the intent?  This will allow us to provide more constructive feedback.

Comment: basically i'm trying to have it take a list of strings is the format of <word>,<letter> and have the function replace <word> with <word> but without <letter>. input.txt contains this:


banana,a
roberto,o
bookkeeper,e
cheerlessness,s
mississippi,i

Comment: How do you think your code matches what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: If it helps, my code is meant to have the same input and output as the following but using a recursive format.

```
with open("input.txt") as file:

    def remove_from_string():

        with open("input.txt") as file:
    
            for line in file:

                string, letter = line.strip().split(",")
   
                res_str = string.replace(letter, '') 
   
                print (res_str + "," + letter)

remove_from_string()
```

Comment: Can you explain what your code does?

Comment: My code removes a given letter from a given word in an input file and out puts the word with the given letter removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coding wwii answer.

**Code**

```
def remove_strings_recursive(lines):
    # Base Case
    if not lines:
        return ""
    
    # with the first item in the list
    # split it on a comma into a word and a letter
    word,letter = lines[0].rstrip().split(',')
    
    # remove all instance of the letter from the word
    word = word.replace(letter, '')
    
    # recurse by returning the word and calling the function with list_of_lines[1:]
    # placing a carriage return between each result 
    return word + '\n' + remove_strings_recursive(lines[1:])

# open the file (just once!)
with open('input.txt', 'r') as file:
    # read all the lines into a list
    lines = file.readlines()
    
    # call the function with the list_of_lines as the argument
    result = remove_strings_recursive(lines)
    print(result)  # Output result to console
```

**Test**

File input.txt

```
banana,a
roberto,o
bookkeeper,e
cheerlessness,s
mississippi,i
```

Output

```
bnn
rbert
bookkpr
cheerlene
msssspp
```

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt has numerous problems - you should start over. Here is an outline/algorithm that should get you started.

- define a recursive function that takes a list of lines as an argument

  - the base case should be an empty list

    - returns an empty string
  - with the first item in the list

    - split it on a comma into a word and a letter
    - remove all instance of the letter from the word
    - recurse by returning the word **and** calling the function with *`list_of_lines[1:]`*
      .
- open the file   (just once!)

  - read all the lines into a list
- call the function with the list_of_lines as the argument